# Weathering of silicates

Tags: geochemistry, rocks, water

I am trying to find a relationship between the silicate-rich rocks weathering products. For example I've found information regarding gabbro weathering in which, according the consulted source, in 100 grams of weathered gabbro, 46.61 g will form laterite  and the remaining 53.39 will be dissolved. In this case the ratio between the leftover and the dissolved part will be 0.87, my idea is to determine a range of ratios for silicate-rich rocks (igneous) for which these relations might be valid.

Does anyone know about more sources where I can find more information regarding the relation between the relationships between the dissolved and the leftovers of weathered rocks, with emphasis in silicate-rich rocks (igneous)?

Comment: What is this source? It seems very specific. The ratio will depend on the initial gabbro composition, the type of climate (tropical vs arid vs cold etc), time (and therefore tectonics), the place within the laterite profile, and much more. You might want to start with a [quick Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=laterite%20formation).